# Vector texture not rendering in EEVEE but showing in viewport

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

I've got absolutely no idea what is going on here, but in the viewport, I see this glow around the edge of objects, which I got by using this configuration for the **world** texture, this is not an object texture.
[image: Result]
[image: Nodes]

I love the effect and it really works in this genre, but whenver I hit F12, the glow sadly disapears. I tried everything I know, but I can't seem to get it to render.
[image: Rendered Image]

This doesn't even show in the viewport with cycles, nor in a cycles render. Of note is also that the edges glimmer/change texture when the camera is moved through the scene.

NOTE: To recreate this you may need to enable bloom.

I made an example of the issue with the default cube and the same world texture, but when I hit render on this, I just get black. : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z7FXgNpQuj-v3R8e7PutohWxCl_XKw1D/view?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hello :). The glow is caused by the *Bloom option* in Eevee. It's basically faked volumetrics. It's not available in Cycles, because Cycles doesn't fake things.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've got bloom enabled, and everthing looks right in the viewport, its just when I hit render, no glow appears round the edges like in the first image.

Comment: if that is a world effect, it is possible that you enabled 'transparent' in the 'film' option

Answer (score 0):

i just could "work" now with your blend file, which is just a cube with emission color.

I got this as result: [image]

1. you can get this effect by adding a particle system to your object.
2. set your particle settings like this:

[image]

3. create a small icosphere with material -> emission color: pink, emission strength: 7 or more
4. use this icosphere in you particle settings as render object